# Como criar uma propriedade de um objeto dinamicamente?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Atualmente estou fazendo dessa maneira, porém ocorre ***erro*** ao dar `build` no projeto:

```
function AddSelectOption(name, item) {
    vm.item = {
         name: item["name"],
         [name]: item[name] //Erro nessa linha
    };
    vm.filters[name].push(vm.item);
}

//call   AddSelectOption('statusID',$item)
```

Comment: Qual o nome da propriedade que você quer criar?

Comment: @jbueno Editei a pergunta.

Comment: @Matheus você quer adicionar um item em uma lista?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Isso, onde esse item em uma de suas propriedades, tem de ser criado dinamicamente.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É só adicionar a propriedade depois de criar o objeto usando a sintaxe `['propriedade']`.

```
function AddSelectOption(name, item) {
    vm.item = {
    };

    vm.item[name] = item;

    vm.filters[name].push(vm.item);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Confirme que `$item` possui uma propriedade `name`.

A criação dinâmica de propriedades computadas funciona perfeitamente na maioria dos browsers modernos:

```js
// Computed property names (ES2015)

function AddSelectOption(name, item) {
    var item = {
         name: item,
         [name]: item
    };
    
console.log(item);
}

AddSelectOption('statusID','teste');
```

Resultado esperado:

```
{
  "name": "teste",
  "statusID": "teste"
}
```